# How to change notification type from Banner to Alert in iOS8?

Tags: ios, notifications, uilocalnotification

I'm trying to create an app that delivers local notifications as an Alert, not a Banner. But looks like banner is the default and I can't find a way to change it on my code. I can change it on the app notification settings and it works perfectly, but I want that configuration to be default.

This is the code I use to ask the user for permission to send notifications:

```
UIUserNotificationSettings* notificationSettings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound categories:nil];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:notificationSettings];
```

(By the way, does someone know why I can't set icon badge with this code?)

And this is the code I use to create the Local Notification:

```
UILocalNotification* localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
        localNotification.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:segundosTotal];
        localNotification.alertBody = timer.nome;
        localNotification.soundName = @"Default-28-sec-192kbps.mp3";
        localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
```

With this code I get the default Banner notification, how can I change that to the Alert one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe there is any way to programmatically force the system to display your notification as an alert rather than as a banner. Looking over the [documentation for `UILocalNotification`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILocalNotification/category) and for [`UIUserNotificationSettings`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIUserNotificationSettings_class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIUserNotificationType), I don't see anything that would allow you to specify that you want an alert instead of a banner.

It's up to the user to adjust their notification settings for your app - I would leave it to them to decide how they want to receive notifications.